# how to remove child(html elements) of div Id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<div id="myId">
   <div>aa</div>
   <h3>hellow</h3>
   <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

So how to remove all content of Id "`myId`" Using jQuery?

The result must be this:

`<div id="myId"></div>`

Comment: `$("myId").empty()`

Comment: *"Please I am waiting for your answear"* You'd be much better off [reading the documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: You are waiting for our answer? Maybe we are waiting for you to show what you have tried so far... Where is your attempt(s) and what appears to be wrong with what you currently have/using?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest Reading this would certainly help about creating a question

Answer (score 1):

you can use remove() method. [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$( "#myId" ).empty()
```

Comment: That would remove the selector from the DOM instead of emptying it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

   > Description: Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```js
$("#myId").empty()

console.log($("#myId").get(0).outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId"><div>aa</div><h3>hellow</h3><a href="#"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use different ways:

```
// ref: https://api.jquery.com/empty/
$("#myId").empty()

// ref: https://api.jquery.com/html/
$("#myId").html('')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove or empty all the elements of a container `div` in this case, you can:

```
$("#myId").empty();
```

OR

```
$("#myId").html('');
```

Reference link to [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: *"Firstly, you are missing #"* How is the OP missing the `#`... the OP hasn't shown any attempt of using jQuery so the whole attempt is missing.

Comment: My miss, I was checking the comments where Guradio has missed the `#`